# Netty: Pipe-ing output of one Channel to the input of an other

Tags: io, pipe, netty, channel

Netty-Gurus,

I've been wondering if there is a shortcut/Netty-Utility/smart-trick
for connecting the input of one Channel to the output of
an other channel. In more details consider the following:

1. Set-Up a Netty (http) server
2. For an **incoming** MessageEvent get its **ChannelBuffer**
3. and **pipe** its **input**  **to** a NettyClient-**ChannelBuffer**
   (which is to be set up along the lines of the NettyServer).

I'm interested in how to achieve **bullet-point** ***3.*** since my first 
thoughts along the lines
    // mock messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e):
    ChannelBuffer bufIn = (ChannelBuffer) e.getMessage();
    ChannelBuffer bufOut = getClientChannelBuffer();// Set-up somewhere else
    bufOut.write(bufIn);

seem to me awkward because
A. I have to determine for each and every messageReceived-Event 
   the target ChannelBuffer
B. To much Low-Level tinkering

My wish/vision would be to connect
--> the input of one Channel
--> to the output of an other channel
and let them do their I/O without any additional coding.

Many thanks in advance!,
Traude

P.S: Issue has arisen as I'm trying to dispatch the various HTTP-requests to the
server (one entry point) to several other servers, depending on 
the input content (mapping based on the first HTTP request line). 
Obviously, I also need to do the inverse trick -- pipeing back client 
to server -- but I guess it'll be similar to the solution of
the question before.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to use a multiplexer in you business handler. The business handler could have a map. With key as "first http request line" and value as the output channel for the server. Once you do a lookup you just do a `channel.write(channelBuffer)`;

Also take a look at bruno de carvalho's [tcp tunnel](https://github.com/brunodecarvalho/malabarista/tree/05ceb50bfdba5ddb5a3529a66df14b1601af69ef), which may give you more ideas on how to deal with these kind of requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the posting!, in detail:  bruno de carvalho's tcp tunnel is

Comment: Thanks for the posting!, in detail:    Bruno de Carvalho's tcp tunnel is close to my   requirements, I need to change it a bit because the tcp tunnel multiplexes based on   connection whereas I need to multiplex based on content (maybe I can integrate the   content-sniffign into Bruno's tunnel and ask him if he's willing to merge these   strategies - it surely leverages our approaches). I was hoping for a pipe-ing like in [link] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html, but I guess in the meantime I could try to provide myself such a pipe-ing.